# How to get the uploaders for a class using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Given a Ruby class

```
Class Profile

  mount_uploader :avatar, MyUploader
  mount_uploader :cover_page, MyUploader
  mount_uploader :fav_cat_pic, MyUploader

end
```

How can I extract the "methods" (i.e. `avatar`, `cover_page` and `fav_cat_pic`) bound to the `MyUploader` at runtime?

Where `MyUploader` inherits from `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `uploaders` method

E.g.
`Profile.uploaders`